# MPI4py error "tmi fabric is not available and fallback fabric is not enabled"

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am running a code that spawns mpi processes with a system call within python.

The code runs fine in some cases, but when I increase the number of workers spawned on a node beyond a certain point i get the following error:

```
can't open /dev/ipath, network down (err=26)
[0] MPI startup(): tmi fabric is not available and fallback fabric is not enabled
```

For example on a node with 16 cpus, i can spawn 12 1 cpu processes and it will run, if I try and spawn 14 i get this error.

Any ideas what is causing it and how to get around it would be welcome.

I am using intel/mpi/64/5.1.3.210.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling fallback fabrics solved this problem for me:

```
mpiexec.hydra -genv I_MPI_FABRICS=dapl,ofa,tcp,tmi,ofi -np 32 _name_of_mpi_executable_here_
```